# Find the most common letter in a word; alphabetically

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

program input is a string. From this string I would want the most common letter. In the case that there are multiple letters with the same frequency, I would return the one that comes first in the latin alphabet

code:

```
def most_Wanted(text="Hello Oman"):
    lst = [x for x in text.replace(" ","").lower() if x.isalpha]
    count = {}
    for letter in lst:
        if letter in count:
            count[letter] += 1
        else:
            count[letter] = 1
    count = list(count.items())
    sorted(count, key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
    print(count[0][0])
```

expected:

```
l #though o and l appear 3 times, l is before o in the latin alphabet
```

output:

```
h #there seems to be an error in the sorting as the first pair of tuples in the list always seems to be the first letter of the text?
```

Any suggestions to spruce up the code would be fine, though I would prefer not using modules at the moment so I can learn the core python. Thank you:)

Comment: Who downvoted this? OP has code, expected and actual output. +1

Comment: sorted() will return the sorted list. `s = sorted(count, key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
    print(s[0][0])`

Comment: Ok, I can see some reasons that warrant a downvote now: first, the first line `def most_Wanted("Hello Oman"):` is invalid syntax, I edited that. Second, I can't reproduce the claimed actual output.

Comment: @Mateusz would sorted function not change the count variable, instead I would have to assign the sorted list to a new variable?

Comment: @timgeb Thanks for editing the post. Also you do not get h as the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `sorted` returns a new list, it is not in-place.

You should either reassign its return value, or use `.sort()`:

```
count = sorted(count, key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
```

or

```
count.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
```

There is also an issue in the line

```
lst = [x for x in text.replace(" ","").lower() if x.isalpha]
```

`if x.isalpha` is always going to return `True` since it is only referencing the function instead of actually calling it. It should be changed to

```
lst = [x for x in text.replace(" ","").lower() if x.isalpha()]
```

Comment: Made a note of this thank you very much:) Is there anything here that is complex and can be simplified?

Comment: @KOOTSHOOTS The entire thing actually. `from collections import Counter ; count = Counter("Hello Oman") ; print(count.most_common()[0][0])`

Comment: Without using modules? Would there be a simpler way

Comment: @KOOTSHOOTS Sure, just run a loop. You can always dig into the `Counter` code and reimplement it yourself.